# Annihilator of an element in a ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\ann{ann}$Let $a$ and $b$ be two non-zero zero divisors of a commutative ring $R$ with 1 such that $\ann(a) \ne \ann(b)$.

is it always possible to find a sequence of non-zero elements $a_1,\dotsc,a_k \in R$ such that $a \in \ann(a_1)$, $a_1 \in \ann(a_2)$, …, $a_{k-1} \in \ann(a_k)$, and $a_k \in \ann(b)$?

Please share your thoughts or some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow some $a_i$ to be $0$, then the answer is obviously yes.

If there are no $0$-divisors in $R$, then the answer is vacuously yes.  If there is a $0$-divisor $a$ in $R$, then taking $b = 1$ gives an example where no such sequence exists.

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ both have non-$0$ annihilators.  Say $x \ne 0 \ne y$ satisfy $a x = 0$ and $b y = 0$.  If $x y \ne 0$, then you may take $a_1 = x y$.  Otherwise, take $a_1 = x$ and $a_2 = y$.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the question accordingly. So for me $a$ and $b$ are non-zero zero divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered by LSpice, but in case you wonder about similar questions in the future, there is a sizable body of work on [zero-divisor graphs of commutative rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-divisor_graph).